# 0x10000000 is a hexadecimal? why is it so long? what value is it in ASCII format?

Tags: java, hex, ascii, message

I'm a junior JAVA developer and I'm supposed to develop some transaction messages. The given specifications include hex value 0x10000000 or 0x20000000, and I'm really bad at data communications, I refer mostly to http://www.asciitable.com/ to help me translate between formats, but I'm really confused about this 0x10000000. In decimal format, it is 268,435,456, unusually big, and I couldn't find anything on ASCII format.

I'm just wondering why they would provide that hex value cause I'm missing something here, and the previous version of this transaction device I'm working on has hex value in 4 characters like 0x33 or 0x31. What are the differences here or what am I missing out here (in terms of understanding)?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x10000000));` - and clearly 268,435,456 is not an ascii character.

Comment: It is just the value, that changed. It is still an hexadecimal ```int``` literal. Since 8 digits are provided after the ```0x```, all 32 bits are addressed (at least more or less..). Your values are the same as ```1 << 28``` and ```1 << 29```.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes I have mentioned "In decimal format, it is 268,435,456, unusually big, and I couldn't find anything on ASCII format."

Comment: Correct. Because ASCII is an 8-bit symbology. Java integers are 32-bits.

Comment: @Islingre thank you so much, i'm sorry but what is 1<<28 and 1<<29?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you, I have tried System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x10000000));, but it's printing me value of 10000000000000000000000000000.. does that mean anything?

Comment: This is bit shifting. Tried telling you, that your values both consist of just one "on" bit, perhaps kind of some flags

Comment: Why do you think this is an ASCII value? Why can't this message be a code stored in a 32-bit integer, without any textual representation?

Comment: @Ken Let's now go one more step: `System.out.printf("%d = %d%n", 0b10000000000000000000000000000, 0x10000000);`

Comment: Nobody is expecting you to convert it to ASCII. It is a 32-bit integer value.

Comment: May this help? [Using Bit Flags and EnumSets in Java](https://eddmann.com/posts/using-bit-flags-and-enumsets-in-java/). You are correct that 0x10000000 is confusing. As you can probably gather from the link, they should not have chosen this value, but an enum constant instead. They chose 0x10000000, and I suppose there’s nothing you can do to change it. Also one often numbers flags from low numbers, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, etc. Why they started from the upper end I don’t know, but technically it works just as well.

Comment: @OleV.V.thank you, I'll have go read that up :)